# Hibernate + Ehcache - IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of composite id

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, ehcache

Searched a lot here, don't found any similar case, sorry if I'm wrong.

My context is a system that uses Hibernate and second level caching.

Previously used these versions (working on production with second level cache enable more than a year):

- **hibernate-ehcache-5.0.9.Final**
- **ehcache-core-2.4.3**
- **ehcache-2.9.0**
- hibernate-core-5.0.9.Final
- others...

Now, upgrading the system, we change the version to:

- hibernate-ehcache-5.2.10.Final
- ehcache-2.10.3
- hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final
- others...

After updated the version of Hibernate and Ehcache started getting this exception above:

```xml
<exception name="IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of br.com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Employee.id">
    org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred calling getter of br.com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Employee.id
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4720)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.toLoggableString(EntityType.java:519)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.toLoggableString(TypeHelper.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.cache.spi.entry.StructuredCacheEntry.destructure(StructuredCacheEntry.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.processCachedEntry(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:612)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromSecondLevelCache(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:602)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1230)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.immediateLoad(SessionImpl.java:1088)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
    at br.com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Employee$$_jvstdd0_3.isActive(Employee_$$_jvstdd0_3.java)
    at br.com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.Test.do(Test.java:30)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TxnSupport.prepare(TxnSupport.java:44)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.prepare(TransactionManager.java:549)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.prepare(TransactionManager.java:615)
    at org.jpos.transaction.TransactionManager.run(TransactionManager.java:291)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@32ed9549
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterMethodImpl.get(GetterMethodImpl.java:41)
    ... 23 more
</exception>
```

My models entities (create for exemplify):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "myregion")
public class Employee implements Serializable { 

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 8467432396096896736L;

     @EmbeddedId
     private EmployeeID id;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name = "id_company", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) 
     private Company company;

     gets & sets
     equals & hashcode
     ...
}
```

```java
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeID implements Serializable { 

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 8467432396096896736L;

     @Column(name = "id_employee", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private Long idEmployee;

     @Column(name = "id_company", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
     private Integer idCompany;

     gets & sets
     equals & hashcode  
     ...
}
```

---

**I verified (making tests) that this mistake occur when hibernate try to hydrate the entity from cache. If i turn off the cache its works.**

**So when rollback the versions, its works again with cache enabled.**

**It's occurs with all my entities have composite keys and are in second level cache**

Answer (score 0):

You have to debug and check why during hydration Hibernate throws the `ClassCastException`. It might be some bug.

However, I also noticed a weirdness in your mapping. Why does both the `@EmbeddedId` attributes and the `@ManyToOne` `@JoinColumn` are set to `insertable = false` and `updatable = false`.

This will make it impossible to ever persist and `Employee` or change its `Company`.

As I explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-composite-primary-key-with-jpa-and-hibernate/), the `@EmbeddedId` should insert and update the composite identifier while the `@ManyToOne` should use `@MapsId`.

Comment: I have reviewed the mapping as you say, using @MapsId, but the bug continue (just to mention).

However, as proof i changed the annotations from "get" methods to attributes.
The error change, now is: 


`"Error accessing field private by reflection for persistent property id : [Ljava.lang.Object;@715ef487">"` 

`"Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set... field id to [Ljava.lang.Object;"`

Have you ever see that? 

https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-10618

Comment: I don't know about this issue. If you can replicate it using [our templates](http://in.relation.to/2016/01/14/hibernate-jpa-test-case-template/), you should open an issue.